# LINQ Group By selecting with many-to-many association table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have two models, `Plans` and `Bookmarks`, which are associated in a `many-to-many relationship` with an association table in the database. Specifically I'm looking at the situation where a `Bookmark` is associated with multiple `Plans`, like below...

```
BookmarkID | PlanID
    A      | 1
    A      | 2
    B      | 2
```

I'd want to select all `BookmarkIDs` where there is **no** association with a particular `PlanID`. So if `PlanID = 1`, I'd want to select B but not A.

For bonus points, I can easily take the BookmarkID result and get all the Bookmarks with a second linq query, but it would be cool to do this inline with a select function or  soemthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use `All` like this:

```
int planId = 1;

var query = from b in context.Bookmarks
            where b.Plans.All(p => p.PlanID != planId)
            select b.BookmarkID;
```

Comment: This is what I eventually ended up using, not sure if it's the same

Comment: var bookmarks = from b in _db.bookmarks
                                      group b by b.BookmarkKey into g
                                      where g.All(b => b.PlanKey != planKey)
                                      join b in _db.Bookmarks on g.Key equals b.BookmarkKey
                                      select b;